SQL lite database with Azure App Service Plan
I'm making an app that uses a SQLite database for storage in Blazor Server. From what I'm reading I can store the SQLite database in the wwwroot folder of the app service storage.
I store data in two locations: one when I'm developing the app and one in the production app's root folder.
This works, but when I deploy the app, the production database is overwritten with the data on my machine.
How do I prevent the database in the wwwroot folder from being overwritten when publishing the application?

Are you deploying your app to Azure via GitHub or Visual Studio?

I'm deploying through Visual Studio

I created Sample Blazor Server App with SQL Lite and deployed to Azure App service.
I deployed my app through Visual Studio and changed Copy to Output Directory from Do not Copy to Copy always for the SQLite database file.
This allows my local machine data to be copied to Azure without being overwritten.
Sql lite Database file -> Right Click -> Properties ->  Copy to Output Directory : Copy always .

Below is my DbContext class and Program.cs class.
DbContext:
using BlazorSqlLite1.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace BlazorSqlLite1.dbcontext
{
    public class AppDbContext:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder1) => optionsBuilder1.UseSqlite(@"Data Source =wwwroot\Demo.db");
        public DbSet<Wallet> wallets {  get; set; }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using BlazorSqlLite1.Data;
using BlazorSqlLite1.dbcontext;
using BlazorSqlLite1.Models;
using BlazorSqlLite1.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<WalletService>(); // Change to Scoped
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();

After Successful deployment, I Added new Value to the Database as shown below.

New Data is added to the database and it is not overwritten the Local Machine data.


if you add data through a development environment, then republish your app, does it overwrite the data on the production server?

@Justin Sinnard Its not overwritten after redeployment.

hhhmm mine is still overwriting the data on the production server.

@Justin Sinners In production, the database file is located in the wwwroot folder, while in development, it is in a different folder. So, did you copy the local database data to the production database file?
